# Creating a PDF from HTML

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I'm trying to create a PDF document from a HTML document. I am using DOMPDF to do this as every other one I found was either too complicated or required me to install something to the web server itself. I just need a very simple HTML to PDF and force download script of some kind. This is my code so far.

It is working almost completely. The ONLY thing that isn't working is the images... For some reason... And it works when I echo the $html variable and load it into a page on it's own.

**PHP**

```
include('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

$html = $html_header . formatFormResultDownload($userid) . $html_footer;

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper("a4");
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('User Gallery (' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ').pdf');
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>****</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%"><img src=
            "http://****.net/client/****/images/logo-large.gif"></td>

            <td width="50%"><span><strong>Email</strong>:
            ****@****.net</span><br>
            <span><strong>Company Name</strong>:****</span><br>
            <span><strong>Company Email</strong>:****</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table border="1" cellpadding="10" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="25%"><span><img src=
            "http://****.net/client/****/index.php?option=com_datsogallery&amp;view=sbox&amp;catid=7&amp;id=70635"
            style="width:200px" width="100%"></span><br>
            <br>
            <span><strong>IS Reference</strong>: 70635</span><br>
            <span><strong>Author</strong>: Rob Speakman</span><br></td>

            <td align="center" width="25%"><span><img src=
            "http://****.net/client/****/index.php?option=com_datsogallery&amp;view=sbox&amp;catid=7&amp;id=71173"
            style="width:200px" width="100%"></span><br>
            <br>
            <span><strong>IS Reference</strong>: 71173</span><br>
            <span><strong>Author</strong>: James Hearne</span><br></td>

            <td align="center" width="25%"><span><img src=
            "http://****.net/client/****/index.php?option=com_datsogallery&amp;view=sbox&amp;catid=7&amp;id=71177"
            style="width:200px" width="100%"></span><br>
            <br>
            <span><strong>IS Reference</strong>: 71177</span><br>
            <span><strong>Author</strong>: James Hearne</span><br></td>

            <td align="center" width="25%"><span><img src=
            "http://****.net/client/****/index.php?option=com_datsogallery&amp;view=sbox&amp;catid=7&amp;id=71171"
            style="width:200px" width="100%"></span><br>
            <br>
            <span><strong>IS Reference</strong>: 71171</span><br>
            <span><strong>Author</strong>: Makiko</span><br></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**The PDF**

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the GD PHP extension enabled?

Comment: Just curious, How does style="width:200px" width="100%" work?

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm editing some legacy code and forgot to update that part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dompdf considers image paths with a full URL (i.e. one with a domain part such as http://example.com/image.png) to be "remote." There are a few settings that are important when handling remote images:

1. `DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE` should be set to true
2. The account running your script (e.g. your web server) needs read/write access to the folder specified by `DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR`
3. dompdf fetches remote images using `file_get_contents()` which will only work if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled (some hosts disable this)
4. dompdf will probably need to use the GD PHP extension for some image processing

It's also important to note that dompdf 0.5.x has problems with dynamically-generated images because it relies heavily on extension for image type detection. You can try to trick it by appending a filename to the end of the URL, but this doesn't always work. The dynamic image problem was addressed in version 0.6.x (currently in beta, but still recommended).

Finally, if you're using dompdf 0.6.x check out the setup file (dompdf/www/setup.php) which will let you know if there are any problems with your installation.

Comment: Okay so it was a combination of 2 things. allow_url_fopen was set to 0 which needed to be swtiched on. In addition, I was using version 0.5 of DOMPDF so needed to upgrade to 0.6 beta. Thanks a lot man. +1.